# smach states based on topic messages

Tags: ros, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

for my project i started to create a SMACH state machine. The state transitions should be based on results from actionservers and their responses and mainly on the data received on one specific topic which contains commands from speech recognition.
The only way i found from tutorials and entries on answers.ros.org is to implement a subscriber in every state of my state machine and work with the data from within this state. As this would produce a lot of duplicate code i would like to know if there is any way to avoid this and handle the incoming data in one place only from which the states can use the data and act accordingly.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52307/smach-states-based-on-topic-messages/) by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2017-12-01**:
I'm facing the same problem. Did you ever figure out a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using actionlib action servers, is there a reason you're not using SimpleActionState?

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1